# Render a new plot when another plot is clicked

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, flask, event-handling

I have 2 plots being rendered initially when the plot_home() is called.However, when I click on each plot, I want it to call a python function plot_parameter() which will render another plot based on which plot is clicked.

I have tried writing this code but I do not know how to detect if first plot is clicked or second plot is clicked. If first plot is clicked, I want to plot a graph and if second plot is clicked I want to plot another graph.
How to make these plot clickable such that it opens another plot when clicked?

```
from flask import Flask
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpld3

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return plot_home()

def onclick(event):
    print 'button=%d, x=%d, y=%d, xdata=%f, ydata=%f'%(event.button, event.x, event.y, event.xdata, event.ydata)
   return plot_parameter()


@app.route('/')
def plot_home():
    fig = plt.figure()
    fig.set_size_inches(5,5)
    parameter_values = [1,2,3,4]
    axis = fig.add_subplot(211)
    axis.plot(parameter_values,'g')
    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)

    parameter_values = [5,6,7,8]
    axis = fig.add_subplot(212)
    axis.plot(parameter_values,'g')
    fig.tight_layout()
    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
    mpld3.show()

 @app.route('/')
 def plot_parameter():
    fig = plt.figure()
    fig.set_size_inches(5,5)
    if(first plot is clicked plot this graph)
        parameter_values = [9,10,11,12]
        axis = fig.add_subplot(211)
        axis.plot(parameter_values,'g')

    if(second plot was clicked plot this graph)
         parameter_values = [13,14,15,16]
         axis = fig.add_subplot(212)
         axis.plot(parameter_values,'g')
    mpld3.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Event handling of images is currently not supported by mpld3 library.
Matplotlib generally supports event handling of images. However, when used with flask, we need to write the matplotlib plot on the canvas as as image because of which event handling is not possible.
The best solution would be to use d3js using javascript. We can return the values to be plotted t html from python and then plot it using d3js which supports event handling of plots.